# How to use Multiple Webviews in bottom of ViewController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview, youtube

[image]

I already had 10 youtube video links on server.Every youtube video should be thumbnail in webview.in a given image the (redbox) show the space is less for showing all youtube thumbnails in webview,so how we can scroll the (redbox) area of viewcontroll and how to create webview at runtime for each youtube link top to bottom in (redbox) area.Any suggestion or help will be appriated.thanx in advance

Comment: You need to show the thumbnail only, right ? don't need to play it there ?

Comment: yes i need only thumbnail here but when we click on any thumbnail it will go to another view to play in webview which is full screenview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For achieving this you can use `scrollview` with `webview`.

First add a scroll view in the view (at the red rectangle's position)

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,150)]; //You need to set the frame according to your need.
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(150,600);
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];
```

Now add ten webviews to that scroll view

```
int yPos = 0;
for(int loop = 0; loop<10;loop++)
{
  UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,yPos,50,50)]
  NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head>
<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head>
<body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">
<div><object width=\"212\" height=\"172\">
<param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param>
<param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>
<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"
type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"212\" height=\"172\"></embed>
</object></div></body></html>";

  //if your video url's are stored in an array then
  NSString *str = (NSString *)[urlArray objectAtIndex:loop];
  [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@str]];
  [scrollView addSubview:webView];
  [webView release];
  webView = nil;
  yPos += 70;
}


[scrollView release];
```

This will add 10 small you tube embedded players in your footer view. You can scroll the footer to see the thumbnails of the video.

Note: You need to change the frames and content size according to your views.

Comment: this will give you a top-bottom scroll, not right-left scroll. If you need that then change the contentSize's width attribute.